# Custom scope in ActiveRecord - Reverse sorting is produced with invalid syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Rails version 4.1.6, Postgres version not important.

I use a custom sorting, where strings come before integers and then integers get sorted as numbers:

sample sorting:

```
A0101
BD330
BE124
1
2
3
10
```

Since there is no direct way to achieve this with the query interface, I've found this `postgres` specific syntax which, in general, works fine:

```
default_scope { 
    order("substring(entries.code, '[^0-9_].*$') ASC").
    order("(substring(entries.code, '^[0-9]+'))::int ASC") 
}
```

For example, to get the first record:

```
2.0.0p247 :001 > Entry.first
  Entry Load (3.6ms)  SELECT  "entries".* FROM "entries"   ORDER BY substring(entries.code, '[^0-9_].*$') ASC, (substring(entries.code, '^[0-9]+'))::int ASC LIMIT 1
 => #<Entry id: ...............>
```

However, when I want to do a reverse search, I get some `DESC` words raining all over the query string... This is quite annoying since I haven't found a way yet to dispose off them:

```
2.0.0p247 :002 > Entry.last
  Entry Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "entries".* FROM "entries"   ORDER BY substring(entries.code DESC, '[^0-9_].*$') DESC, (substring(entries.code DESC, '^[0-9]+'))::int DESC LIMIT 1
PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DESC"
LINE 1: ... FROM "entries"   ORDER BY substring(entries.code DESC, '[^0...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "entries".* FROM "entries"   ORDER BY substring(entries.code DESC, '[^0-9_].*$') DESC, (substring(entries.code DESC, '^[0-9]+'))::int DESC LIMIT 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DESC"
LINE 1: ... FROM "entries"   ORDER BY substring(entries.code DESC, '[^0...
```

To be more specific, which I believe is not necessary, I would like to get rid of those `DESC` within the `substring()` methods...

**EDIT:**

I see in definition of `reverse_sql_order`, that the string is split at the commas `,` and `ASC` or `DESC` is applied there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using extensive database-oriented functions in a Rails project is never a good idea. Those kind of composite statements can drive you insanely crazy.

```
order("substring(entries.code, '[^0-9_].*$') ASC").
order("(substring(entries.code, '^[0-9]+'))::int ASC")
```

IMHO, the simplest and more effective solution is an helper column. Define, for instance, a table column called `weight` with type integer.

Define a model callback that, every time you save an object, stores in the column 0 if the value of the sorting field is a string, the digit if the value is a number. Here's your sort index.

Run the sort queries against that `weight` column. You can even index the attribute, and your queries will be much cleaner and faster. You will also be able to sort by DESC or ASC with no complexity at all.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it is a quite good idea. I'll wait a bit to see if something comes up that will cover me. Overriding `reverse_sql_order` works for me, but as you will probably say, if composing custom sql statements is not a good idea, overriding ActiveRecord is a potential disaster...

Comment: I've applied your suggestion and it was easier to implement then what I first thought. It works great too. Thanks.

Comment: @simone has this right.  Databases have collations for sorting and they are not something you want to reimplement. You'll get characters with accents, UTF8 characters and all sorts of other unexpected behavior.